# 'alt' inside span

Tags: javascript, html, alt

If 'alt' is inside 'span' would I need to change the following script

```
        function setNavi( $c, $i ) {
                var title = $i.attr( 'alt' );
                $('#title').text( title );

                var current = $c.triggerHandler( 'currentPosition' );
                $('#pagenumber span').text( current+1 );

            }

    $(function() {

        $('#carousel').carouFredSel({
            debug: true,
            responsive: true,
            circular: false,
            auto: true,
            prev: '#prev',
            next: '#next',
            items: {
                visible: 1,
                width: 200,
                height: '66%'
            },
            scroll: {
                onBefore: function( $oI, $nI ) {
                    setNavi( $(this), $nI );
                }
            },
                onCreate: function( $vI ) {
                    setNavi( $(this), $vI );
                }
            });
```

html:

```
<div id="carousel">
<span id="1"><img src="images/someimage.jpg"  alt="sometitle" /></span>
<span id="2"><img src="images/someimage2.jpg" alt="sometitle2" /></span>
</div>

<div id="navi">
 <p id="pagenumber">Now showing image <span></span> of 7.</p>
 <p id="title"></p>
</div>
```

the pagenumber is displaying correctly, but not the image title. also tried using 'title' instead of 'alt' but it still results in a blank title.

Comment: Well, depends on what you pass as `$i`...

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you would. `alt` is for images. Judging by the code, I'd say that the `title` attribute is a suitable alternative, and it will even show the same tooltip that `alt` does for images.

Answer (score 9):

You dont need to do this, its semantically **incorrect**. There is `title` field for span. Use that instead of `alt`.

Comment: if I use 'title' instead of 'alt', would the above script still be incorrect? I'm assuming that it's not reading title or alt because the img tag is inside a span tag. is that correct?

Comment: r@user1184254, Of course you have modify it to check of title attribute

Comment: aside from changing 'alt' to 'title' in the script and html, is there anything else to modify? it seems that either which way it's not displaying the title.

Answer (score 0):

If the `$i` object doesn't contain an `alt` attribute, then you can't assign it as the text of another element. It doesn't matter if the element is inside another, it depends on what **parameter** you're passing through your function. As Sime said, it depends what `$i` is.

Comment: hmm. if I understand correctly it should find the 'alt' text in the img tag and display in div "title". this is to add a caption under the image. @Starx, tried title attribute with same result (blank). update to question added.